# Android application works nice in emulator, but SIGBUS on device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-ndk

I'm doing an application that's uses a library to parse xml, compiled with ndk. For some reason the application works just right in android emulator, but when used in a device doesn't.

More precisely after increasing a pool of memory, when assigning a value to the next free space of that pool, just like this:

*(pool->ptr) = 0

I have heard [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-porting/browse_thread/thread/3fdce181f3154475/140aff6cc1d14a2b?fwc=2), that in some cases the emulator just "passes by" some situations like this just simply by printing or using the memory without crashing the application.

I'm having some trouble trying to find the reason for this and more trouble to find the solution, can some one help me. Many thanks in advance. All the help is welcome.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Are you checking return codes from the resize? Might you have run out of memory?

Comment: Sorry for my late (some decades) response. But to sum up, the source of the issue was on the library I used and for some reason it did not have impact on the emulator. Probably due to the additional resources on memory.